# How tell Eureka Client which port to register (Spring Cloud)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have an Eureka Client implemented with Spring Boot with two active ports:
9005 for https and 9010 for http.

Https is implemented natively by Spring Boot. Http is just an additional simple `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` added in the code.

Now the problem is that this Eureka Client registers itself with the https port specified in the application properties as 9005:

```
server:
   port: 9005
   ssl:
      enabled: true
      ...
   http:
      port: 9010
      address: 127.0.0.1
```

but I would like that this client registers itself with the http port 9010.

Of course the Eureka Server itself is running on the `localhost` and all other registered services are on the localhost too, talking http only.

Https is for external clients that are not WEB browsers and custom certificates are in use there.

I've tried `nonSecurePort` on the Client side, but that seems be to a server-side only configuration parameter. My Eureka Client's configuration (in addition to the port's configuration defined above):

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
    nonSecurePortEnabled: true
    nonSecurePort: 9010
```

Additional HttpServer implementation:

```
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(@Value("${server.http.port}") int httpPort, @Value("${server.http.address}") String httpHost) throws UnknownHostException {
    Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    connector.setPort(httpPort);
    connector.setAttribute("address", InetAddress.getByName(httpHost).getHostAddress());
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
    return tomcat;
}
```

Comment: `eureka.instance.non-secure-port` is the way to go.  It is not a server side only configuration. The trouble is, with your configuration, the secure port is also active and eureka defaults to this if it is. If you don't want secure port disable it in `eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=false`.

Comment: @spencergibb, did not help :( I've even tried setting explicitly health-check-url, etc. The settings seems to be simply ignored. Some configuration problem?     `hostname: localhost non-secure-port-enabled: true
    non-secure-port: 9010
    secure-port-enabled: false
    health-check-url: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.non-secure-port}/ctx/health
    status-page-url: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.non-secure-port}/ctx/info
    home-page-url: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.non-secure-port}/ctx`

Comment: Sorry, ctx prefix in my previous comment was wrong. And the urls are not fully ignored. If I press on the link, it opens the page specified in the status-page-url. However the web GUI on the Eureka server still shows the https port, as well as the log indicates port 9005 (https). Also in the logs I first get the "registering service..." message from com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient and only afterwards "Tomcat started on port(s): 9005 (https) 9010 (http) with context path '' "...

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this, i am not able to set the port the service registers itself with Eureka either

Comment: @waqask87, no I gave up. I've implemented my own https ServletContainer instead of http. So http became native, while https was implemented with the help of TomcatServletWebServerFactory and org.springframework.boot.web.server.Ssl. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dime can you please post your solution as an answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around this is to add the SSL connector as an additional connector and keep the non secure connector as the default one.

Adding the SSL connector as an additional connector:

```
@Configuration
public class HttpsConfiguration {

    @Value("${sslConfig.key-alias}")
    private String keyAlias;

    @Value("${sslConfig.key-store}")
    private String keyStoreFile;

    @Value("${sslConfig.key-password}")
    private String keyPassword;

    @Value("${sslConfig.key-store-type}")
    private String keyStoreType;

    @Value("${sslConfig.port}")
    private int sslPort;

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createSslConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
        connector.setScheme("https");
        connector.setSecure(true);
        protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);

        connector.setPort(sslPort);
        protocol.setKeystoreFile(keyStoreFile);
        protocol.setKeystorePass(keyPassword);
        protocol.setKeyAlias(keyAlias);
        protocol.setKeystoreType(keyStoreType);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Corresponding configuration for the connector:

```
sslConfig:
    key-alias: ode-https
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-password: password
    key-store: ode-https.jks
    port: 443
```

If you are not sure how to generate a keypair, you could use the below command as a starting point:

```
keytool -genkey -alias ode-https -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keys ize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore ode-https.jks
```

Answer (score 1):

I pull the answer out of a comment above, to make it more visible.

I find no direct solution to the problem, so I've implemented my own https `ServletContainer` instead of http. 
Meaning http became native, while https was implemented with the help of `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` and `org.springframework.boot.web.server.Ssl`.

For initializing TomcatServletWebServerFactory, see here:
https://www.baeldung.com/embeddedservletcontainercustomizer-configurableembeddedservletcontainer-spring-boot

```
@Component
public class CustomContainer implements
     WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

  @Override
  public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
     factory.setContextPath("");
     factory.setPort(443);
  }
}
```

To enable SSL:

```
Ssl ssl = new Ssl();
ssl.setEnabled(true);
// set your keystore here if required
...
// assign ssl to the new Tomcat instance
factory.setSsl(ssl);
```

I hope this helps. I do not post an exact code snippet here, as unfortunately in some big companies (that are crazy about their IP rights and possible conflicts with OSS licenses) it creates more troubles than help. Please google for https and TomcatServletWebServerFactory examples.

Comment: This is same as the comment, adding the code and configuration you did for achieving this is what will help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue when deploying a Spring Boot app on Cloud Foundry after enabling Spring Security. The funny part being I haven't enabled HTTPS on the app (only the 8080 port) but the URL registered with Eureka Server points to the port 443.

I've managed to fix the problem adding the following lines on the app's `application.properties` (the 1st line is for using the container-to-container network and the last two did the trick that this question is about).

```
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=false
eureka.instance.nonSecurePort=8080
```

I'm using Spring Boot `2.2.8.RELEASE` and Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR6`